# Unable to understand JWT and Java (Spring Boot).Is this application secure?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

I'm following a Udemy course in attempt to build my first Spring Boot application. Rather than using Spring Security, they are using [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) to implement stateless authentication.

The front end is in Angular, and because it runs on it's own server, CORS is used to open everything up so that the Angular app can hit the Java backend API.

I'm worried that this will open the door to CSRF or other security holes.

After some digging I found similar code to what the Udemy course is using [here](https://github.com/nielsutrecht/jwt-angular-spring), but I don't know enough about security to know if it's enough.

The code in question is as follows:

Filter:

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req,
                     final ServletResponse res,
                     final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header.");
    }

    final String token = authHeader.substring(7); // The part after "Bearer "

    try {
        final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
    }
    catch (final SignatureException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Invalid token.");
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Cors Config:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true); //usually want this
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");//not sure if secure?
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Filter added to main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter((Filter) new JwtFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");

    return registrationBean;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

So is this sort of setup secure enough to be used in production code, or is a more robust solution needed?

Or is there a better way entirely to do stateless authentication? If they were both running on the same domain I wouldn't need CORS right?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use JWT for security purposes. JWT contains information other than random keys which should not be present in the authorisation header. Although we can sign a JWT token, yet we should avoid it. Instead save the extra information in the database and query it whenever you receive the token at server side to check authenticity of the token. Also, the algorithm type none can prove to be a security disaster if exploited by an attacker. Use simple random string as token. Fairly simple and more secure. Confidential information resides in database and not in the token and we all know that databases are very secure.